# Can't send an updated value of the variable from one project to another in the same solution

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to change the value of a variable in one project:

```
public string test;
public void Test (string _result)
{
    test = _result;
   //here i want to update the value of my variable 
}
//Below there is a condition from one of my methods
if (result == 0)
{   
    Test(_client.ErrorText(result));
}
```

Now i'd like to receive this variable in xaml.cs:

```
private void AddString (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _test = test    
    ListBox.Items.Add(_test);           
}
```

As a result the program adds only the default  value of my variable to the ListBox. Later even if the varaible has been changed in the Test() method, the value added to the ListBox is still the same. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, that is perfectly expected behavior. Since `test` is nothing but an ordinary CLR field, it DOES NOT notify WPF or any other GUI on changes that took place at certain moment. 
   I assume you'd like to do it right way? In such a case it is necessary to rewrite much of your code. 
   1) Implement INotifyPropertyChanged intreface on your class. So it looks like `public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged`.
   2) Convert your string filed to the string property, and raise PropertyChanged event in a setter method. Consider following scratch:

```
public string Test { 
   get { return _test; }
   set {
      _test = value;
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...);
   }
}
```

The last line in the setter will notify WPF on changes happed to the specified property and it will be updated in your UI automatically.
   3) Last step. WPF provides a rich binding environment. Let us assume you have a TextBlock intended to render `Test` property content. Then it have to be somehow alike:
    `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}" />`.
   Please pay attention that binding won't work unless the `TextBlock`'s or any it's parent has not-null `DataContext` property. There are many ways to assign it, but for simplicity sake, I assume you'll do it in your Window (very very root element) constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = new MyClass();
```

That's it.

Comment: Im not sure that this is the issue, since he already calls Listbox.Items.add

Comment: I've made changes according to your suggestions and it works well. Thank you